# If $a>0$, then $b<0 \implies ab < 0 $?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to prove that:

> If $a>0$, then $b<0 \implies ab < 0 .$

And I have:

> $a,b>0 \implies ab>0\tag {7'}$

I wrote:

As $a>0$ and $ab<0$ then $b <0$, otherwise this would contradict $7'$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is almost fine. Since the negation of $b\lt 0$ is $b\ge 0$, we need to deal with the possibility that $b=0$.

Comment: Suppose contrapositively:  $ab \geq 0$. Since $a >0$, $\frac{1}{a} > 0$, and so it follows that $\frac{1}{a} (ab) \geq 0 \implies b \geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Say that $a > 0$ and $b < 0.$ Assume for the sake of contradiction that
$ab \geq 0.$ By the definition of positive number,
$$\frac{ab}{a} \geq \frac{0}{a} = 0
\implies b \geq 0,$$
which is a contradiction of the fact that $b < 0.$ Thus,
$$ab < 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

It does contradict $(7')$ though I think the better way to set it up is probably something like this: if $b<0$, then $0<(-b)$. What happens if you multiply by $a$ now?